# Eval doesn't show column from database in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval

I have a database of countries with an that have a Name and an Id.

This is the codebehind.

```
CountriesEntities context = new CountriesEntities();
using (context)
{
    this.gridViewCountries.DataSource = context.Countries;
    this.gridViewCountries.DataBind();
}
```

And when I put this in the html, it works as expeted, showing all the columns and the each country's info.
`<asp:GridView ID="gridViewCountries" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"/>`

But when I change the GridView to the this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewCountries" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <asp:Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Name
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span><%# Eval("Name") %></span>  
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </asp:Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

nothing shows on the page and I have no idea why. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

In a `GridView`, I usually use `Bind` for this, not `Eval`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <span><%# Bind("Name") %></span>  
</ItemTemplate>
```

If that doesn't work, the only other possibility I can think if is that the `Datasource` that's bound to your `GridView` doesn't have a column named "Name" (for some reason).

**Edit:**

Actually, you might also want to try using that inside a server-side `Label` control:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>  
</ItemTemplate>
```